# SaveChanges() not taking any affect

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to add new records to the database, everything goes right without any exceptions, but I don't see the new record the database, here is the code:

```
            aSham_MeterReading meterReading = new aSham_MeterReading();
            meterReading.TimeStampUTC = reading.TimeOfReading;
            meterReading.TimeStampLocal = reading.TimeOfReading.ToLocalTime();
            meterReading.Value = reading.Reading * this.Translate(this.MeterUnitsEnum, reading.FactorIndex);
            meterReading.Meter = meter;
            meterReading.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            meterReading.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            meterReading.RowStatus = "Active";
            db.aSham_MeterReading.Add(meterReading);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

The code above is called like 20 times per second, is there any chance that this is related to the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call it once instead of 20 times a second and see if that's affecting it.

Comment: This code is as basic as it gets and should work. See if any Exceptions are caught after the call to SaveChanges. Or perhaps you are looking at the wrong database!

Comment: what is the value of the CopyToOutputDirectory of the dbfile on your project?

Comment: @Shoe same thing happens when i call it once ...

Comment: @terrybozzio I'm not using a database file within the project

Comment: please look in your bin/debug folder,you can do that in solution explorer.

Comment: @Dabblernl i tried adding a record to another table in the same DB and it worked, but for this table i'ts not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the return value from db.SaveChanges() , if it is actually successful , it returns 1 . This will let you know if the operation was actually successful or not

```
int returnCode = db.SaveChanges();
if(returnCode == 1 )
{
   Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Something gone wrong");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful information, the return code was 2

Comment: SaveChanges returns the number of objects written to the database. Anything above 0 should indicate success.

Comment: The return value means that the data is saved to the database. You are looking at the wrong database.

Comment: Thanks @Dabblernl , it was a DateTime issue